# Delete until the start of next visible line?

Tags: vimscript, indentation, macos

I'm using MacOS.

As title, for example before the command:

```
$('h1#title')
.css({'font-size': '80px', 'text-align': 'center'}_)_

    .text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

(Notice that the blank line above `.text()` is intended.)

and `_)_` means the cursor  is on the char `)`, then what I want to achieve is that after some command the result will be:

```
$('h1#title')
.css({'font-size': '80px', 'text-align': 'center'}).text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

The result of `3J` will output:

```
$('h1#title')
.css({'font-size': '80px', 'text-align': 'center'}) .text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

Comment: `3J` doesn't work?

Comment: @BLayer: If the `.someMethod()` is on the next line, the result will be `someFunction() .someMethod()`, i.e. a space in between `someFunction()` and `someMethod()`, which is not what I want.

Comment: @BLayer: Yes, but both will have a space between. Sorry for my bad example, let me update my question.

Comment: @BLayer: I have checked that there is no space after the `_)_`.

Comment: Try it after doing `:set fo& cpo&` just to make sure you have the same config that I'm testing with.

Comment: @BLayer: The same result. Is it related to the fact that I'm using neovim?

Comment: You know what...it looks like it's a Windows vs *nix thing. I'm using the same vimrc for both but I get space with *nix and no space with Windows. A CRLF related thing perhaps.

Comment: @BLayer: Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this brute-force looks verbose but it actually speedy:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent> J mm+:left<CR>i<BS><ESC>`m
```

Intended behaviour:

- The trailing space(s) on the starting line is kept.
- The cursor will be at the same starting place before/after the command.

Side-effect:

- Your mark `m` will be overwritten.

#### Testing 1:

Given:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'})

    .text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

Got:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'})
    .text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

#### Testing 2:

Given:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'})
    .text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

Got:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'}).text()
    .testing()
    .tset()
```

#### Testing 3:

Given == Got:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'}).text().testing().tset()
(EOF)
```

#### Testing 4:

Given:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'}

        .text()
        .testing()
        .tset()
```

Got:

```
.css({'font-size':█'80px', 'text-align': 'center'}
        .text()
        .testing()
        .tset()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution: `d/\S<CR>`, meaning "delete up to the next non-space character."

Unfortunately, the delete includes the current character, so either `a`  to append a space after the `)`, or `:set virtualedit=all` and `l` to move to a non-existent part of line, simulating said space.

Or just, ya know, `2Jx` (or even `J.x`, or `JJx`), all of which are shorter…